# jquery toggle slide from left to right and back

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, toggle

I have a "Menu" button on the left hand side of the page and once selected I have a div containing the menu items show.  I then have another button that can be selected to hide the menu.

Ideally I want this to slide out (from left to right) and back but have been unsuccessful in getting this working well. I have tried using animate and SlideToggle but none work well for what I have. Any tips?

```
<div id="cat_icon">Menu</div>
<div id="categories">
    <div CLASS="panel_title">Menu</div>
    <div CLASS="panel_item">
        <template:UserControl id="ucCategories" src="UserControls/ProductCategories.ascx" />
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('#cat_icon').click(function () {
    $('#categories').toggle();
    $('#cat_icon').hide();
});
$('.panel_title').click(function () {
    $('#categories').toggle();
    $('#cat_icon').show();
});
```

Comment: Here is a good tutorial on how to slide http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions

Comment: Clicking on #cat_icon will both hide (with toggle()) the #categories and the #cat_icon itself, is this the intended behaviour?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See this: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QDUQk/)

```
$('#cat_icon,.panel_title').click(function () {
   $('#categories,#cat_icon').stop().slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Update : To slide from left to right: [Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/QDUQk/1/)

**Note**: Second one uses jquery-ui also

Answer (score 13):

Sliding from the right:

```
$('#example').animate({width:'toggle'},350);
```

Sliding to the left:

```
$('#example').toggle({ direction: "left" }, 1000);
```

Comment: This worked. My full code :

$('document').ready(function () {
  $(".exampleDivToClick").click(function(){
  $(".exampleDivToSlide").animate({width: 'toggle'});
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
 });
});

Answer (score 6):

Hide `#categories` initially

```
#categories {
    display: none;
}
```

and then, using JQuery UI, animate the `Menu` slowly

```
var duration = 'slow';

$('#cat_icon').click(function () {
    $('#cat_icon').hide(duration, function() {
        $('#categories').show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, duration);});
});
$('.panel_title').click(function () {
    $('#categories').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, duration, function() {
        $('#cat_icon').show(duration);});
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VXWyg/5/)

You can use any time in milliseconds as well

```
var duration = 2000;
```

If you want to hide on `class='panel_item'` too, select both `panel_title` and `panel_item`

```
$('.panel_title,.panel_item').click(function () {
    $('#categories').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, duration, function() {
        $('#cat_icon').show(duration);});
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VXWyg/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Use this...

```
$('#cat_icon').click(function () {
    $('#categories').toggle("slow");
    //$('#cat_icon').hide();
});
$('.panel_title').click(function () {
    $('#categories').toggle("slow");
    //$('#cat_icon').show();
});
```

See this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/uu7ZB/)

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method as **slideLeft()** and **slideRight()** which looks like [slideUp()](https://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and [slideDown()](https://api.jquery.com/slideDown/), but you can simulate these effects using jQuery’s [animate()](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) function.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum.</div>
```

**JQuery Code:**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var DivWidth = $(".text").width();
    $(".left").click(function(){
      $(".text").animate({
        width: 0
      });
    });
    $(".right").click(function(){
      $(".text").animate({
        width: DivWidth
      });
    });
  });
```

You can see an example here: [How to slide toggle a DIV from Left to Right?](https://stackhowto.com/how-to-slide-toggle-a-div-from-left-to-right/)