# How to reverse the direction of the jquery UI fold effect?

Tags: jquery

I am using the jquery UI fold effect as a parameter in toggle, like so:

```
$(textDivChild).toggle( "fold");
```

It works great, I only have one problem. The div folds from right to left instead of left to right, which is what I want. And I do not see a direction option in the options object... I've tried various other methods like slide, slideUp (in jquery core) and slideDown but none of them do what I want. If slide had a direction option for sliding "up left" rather than just "up," I could use it. My ultimate goal is to have the container appear like it is collapsing/expanding into/out of a button -- fold would work great for this if only I could reverse the direction.

Also, I have tried right aligning the div with relative/absolute positioning and it has no effect of the direction. I wouldn't be able to do that anyway because I cannot position right because of how the application I am doing this on top of works ... I can only use "left" and "top" CSS positioning anyway.

Comment: More: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438577/jquery-toggle-slide-from-left-to-right-and-back

Comment: @isherwood I've read that question multiple times and its answers. slideToggle() does not have a feature to change the direction nor does slideUp() and slideDown(), despite their names.

Comment: Did you look at the demo provided? http://jsfiddle.net/QDUQk/1/

Comment: I'll retract my close vote because I put the wrong question in as the duplicate, but this has already been asked and answered.

Comment: @isherwood did you read my question? Slide does not cut it, I have already tried. I have a need to expand/contract in and out of a central point on the screen (think a point on the x and y axis). Slide only allows you to expand/contract from a direction. Fold is designed to expand/contract from a central point only you cannot reverse the direction (my problem). P.S. I have thoroughly googled this question and have read articles for about an hour before posing my question.

Comment: Ah. That wasn't clear to me. In that case, look at animate(). That's been answered also: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+expand+from+center+animate

Comment: @isherwood animate is an option but it complicates things drastically. I'd really like to make use of jquery's toggle method because my ultimate goal is to toggle show/hide an element.

Comment: Maybe post some sample HTML that we can fiddle with.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS, you could use the `float` attribute to make it [look like it's folding to the right](http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/ncXPZ/).

```
#textDivChild {
    float: right;
}
```

All this does is align everything right so even though the animation is happening exactly the same as before, it will appear as though it's folding to the right.

Comment: This is a possible solution. If only the application I am doing all of this on top of would allow me to use the float property (it's complicated). Let me see if I can wrap it in a dummy div positioned with float:right ... I'll report back.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a feasible solution for me ... Floating right would require a lot of code rewriting and I'm not even sure if it would work (not sure my application would allow me to float something right where it is). Kind of sucks that I have to use CSS to change how a javascript function works. Seems to me there should be an option for reversing the fold direction.

Comment: But otherwise, this is a perfect solution. I'd upvote you if I had enough reputation (new account).

Comment: @ChrisScott Not a problem, what CSS properties do you have access to?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. You only need to use some special CSS formatting.

What I do is setting up a "position: absolute;" and point the position with "right/top/left/bottom".

- If you setting up left - it would start from left
- If you setting up right- it would start from right
- If you setting up top- it would start from top
- If you setting up bottom- it would start from bottom

You can also decide what to start first - horizontal or vertical like this

```
$('#hover_settings').toggle({effect: "fold", horizFirst: false}, 500);
```

or

```
$('#hover_settings').toggle({effect: "fold", horizFirst: true}, 500);
```

The last parameter is obviously - time for effect. :)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mynewbox/x0quktck/1/)

```js
$(function() {
    function t(){
         $('#hover_settings')
        .toggle({effect: "fold", horizFirst: false}, 500);
    }
    
    
$('#button_settings1').click(function(){
    $('#hover_settings')
        .css('left','1.4em')
        .css('bottom','3em')
        .css('right','initial')
        .css('top','initial')    
   t(); 
});

$('#button_settings2').click(function(){
        $('#hover_settings')
        .css('right','2em')
        .css('top','2em')
        .css('left','initial')
        .css('bottom','initial')
   t(); 
});

    
});
```

```css
#settings_wrapper{
 position:relative;
 background: aliceblue;
 display:inline-block;

}

#hover_settings{
 position: absolute;
 /*right: -20em;
 top: -6em;*/
 background: antiquewhite;
 border-radius: 20px;
 border: 2px solid #ccc;
 width: 10em;
 height: 5em;
 text-align: center; 
 display: none;
 /*left: 1.4em;*/
 /*bottom: 3em;*/
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>        
<div id='settings_wrapper'>
    <button id='button_settings1'>btn1</button>
    ..............................................
    <button id='button_settings2'>btn2</button>
    <div id='hover_settings'>
        Settings
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution is better than "floating" for the number of reasons.

1) It allows to set not only horizontal, but also vertical direction.

2) In "floated" objects you cannot use vertical alignment.